# Using a portlet in Liferays Control Panel

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I am trying to write a simple portlet, that can be both configured in the portlets edit mode for user-specific settings and in the Control Panel of Liferay (6.1) for administrative settings.

I was able to add my portlet to the Control Panel, but it shows the standard view mode on opening - how can I show another view in Control Panel than in the normal view mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the standard view mode is what you get in controlpanel. However, you can analyze the current group (or scopeGroup) by accessing the ThemeDisplay object (an attribute in the request), validate that you're in controlpanel and then dispatch to another view. Nothing limits you to just a single screen in view mode.

Another option is to distinguish between the portlet that is used on general pages and have a specific portlet for ControlPanel. IMHO this is a bit cleaner, separates both responsibilities nicely from each other.